# Error when parsing string to ignore whitespace, Calculator class

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm learning Java and I've been coding a calculator class. For now, it is only designed to do simple operations with two numbers, e.g. 2 + 2. Here is a small section of my code:

```
public static void start()
{
    System.out.println("Calculator. Type \"exit\" to quit.");
    System.out.print("> ");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
    String entry = scan.nextLine();

    while (! (entry.equals("exit")))
    {           
        String [] values = entry.replaceAll("(^\\s+|\\s+$)", "").split("\\s+");

        num1 = new Double(values[0]);
        operand = values[1];
        num2 = new Double(values[2]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

After this comes a switch statement which is part of the while loop. The switch statement tests the value of `operand`, calls the appropriate method, prints the result, and then restarts the while loop.

I did not code the regex portion myself, but from reading previous StackOverlfow posts, I learned that it will ignore any whitespace characters before, in-between, and after the values I want.

The code works fine, except for when whitespace characters do not separate `num1`, `operand`, and `num2`.

For instance:

`>         2  +             2`

`4.0`

`>2 + 2`

`4.0`

But:

`>2+2`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2+2"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
    at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:597)
    at calc.Calc.start(Calc.java:24)
    at calc.CalcClient.main(CalcClient.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

And:

`>2+ 2`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2+"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
    at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:597)
    at calc.Calc.start(Calc.java:24)
    at calc.CalcClient.main(CalcClient.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

And:

`>2 +2`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at calc.Calc.start(Calc.java:26)
    at calc.CalcClient.main(CalcClient.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

Where is my mistake? Is it a problem with the array, the way I parse the string, or something else perhaps? I'd like to code it so the user can input something with as much whitespace as they want, or none at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because you are splitting on white space and when the + is not separated he's passed as value with the 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided as an example:

```
    // extract the operands and operator
    String[] operandsArrStr = "22+ 2".replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[\\+\\-\\/\\*]"); // {"22", "2"}
    String operator = "22+ 2".replaceAll("(\\s+|\\d+|\\.)", ""); // "+"

    // convert the values to doubles
    Double[] operands = new Double[operandsArrStr.length];
    for (int i=0; i < operandsArrStr.length; i++) {
        operands[i] = new Double(operandsArrStr[i]);
    }

    Double res = null;
    // calc
    if ("+".equals(operator)) {
        res = operands[0] + operands[1]; // assuming only two operands and one operator!
    }
    else if ("-".equals(operator)) {
        res = operands[0] - operands[1];
    }
    else if ("/".equals(operator)) {
        res = operands[0] / operands[1];
    }
    else if ("*".equals(operator)) {
        res = operands[0] * operands[1];
    }
    System.out.println("res = " + res); // prints 24.0
```

Comment: This solution would also break 2-digits numbers (e.g.: `10`) in two tokens. For example, if `entry` is like `"10 + 1"`, `values` will contain `["1", "0", "+", "1"]`.

Comment: @ccjmne I just posted a comment about that

Comment: I think that your suggestion is actually the most sensible solution ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried `String [] values = entry.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[\\+\\-\\/\\*\\^\\%]")` but I get an error no matter what I enter. Did I misinterpret what you meant?

(I have exponentiate and modulus methods in addition to +, -, /, *)

Comment: @pez yes, if you split on the operator you need to also find which operator was submitted and take the proper action `[+-*/]`

Comment: Thanks! This works. Although I'm not sure if you can do `Double res = null`. I just set `Double res = 0` before my switch statement.

Comment: @alfasin This solution works with all whitespace combinations I've tried, but it won't work if my operands are decimals. For instance, `2.2 * 2.2` will not work. How can I adjust the regex expressions to allow decimals?

Comment: @pez the operator regex should be changed. See fix above.

Comment: @pez you definitely should, it's a good tool to have in your toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

This is a **regex** problem, actually :)

You should replace that line:

```
String [] values = entry.replaceAll("(^\\s+|\\s+$)", "").split("\\s+");
```

... by:

```
String [] values = entry.trim().split("\\s*");
```

---

***Explanation:***

- Actually, `String#trim` removes all the eventual white spaces at the beginning and the end of a `String`. I believe that's what you're trying to do with `.replaceAll("(^\\s+|\\s+$)", "")`
- Second, `\s+` in a **regex** means *"at least ONE white space character"*, while `\s*` mean *"any sequence of white space characters"* (including **no** white space at all, which is a valid case for you ;)

---

However, I'd actually suggest you to try a different approach. Consider the sample piece of working code below:

```
private static final Pattern SIMPLE_OPERATION = Pattern.compile("(?<num1>\\d*\\.?\\d+)(?<operand>[+-/*])(?<num2>\\d*\\.?\\d+)");

public static void start() {
    System.out.println("Calculator. Type \"exit\" to quit.");

    try (final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        Double num1, num2;
        String operand;
        String entry;

        do {
            System.out.print("> ");
            entry = scan.nextLine();

            final Matcher m = SIMPLE_OPERATION.matcher(entry.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
            if (m.matches()) {
                num1 = Double.valueOf(m.group("num1"));
                num2 = Double.valueOf(m.group("num2"));
                operand = m.group("operand");

                System.out.println(String.format("'%s', '%s', '%s'", num1, operand, num2));
            }
        } while (!(entry.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")));
    }
}
```

This can be easily enhanced in the future and can handle anything like:

```
2+2
  2  * 2 
2 -  2
2 / 2
```

... and also decimal numbers:

```
88     +   65.005555
.5*2
```

I hope this'll help you to get started ;)

Comment: This works for "2+2", but won't work for e.g. "2 + 2". It results in values being ['2', ' ', '+', '2']

Comment: I think the OP's requirements are that after the split that they're left with an array of 3 elements. I guess I'm misunderstanding your code; if you provide a standalone piece of code it would become clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `String [] values = entry.trim().split("\\s*");` but that actually doesn't work for either `2 + 2` or `2+2`. If I use `String [] values = entry.trim().split("\\s+");`, it will look much nicer, but still has the same problems as my original post.

Comment: @ccjmne Thanks for the help. I'm going to read up on the second code you posted so I can understand what it does rather than simply copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works and comes with test cases in a standalone executable file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(\\D)\\s*(\\d+)");
        String[] tests = {"2+2", "2 + 2", "   2 +     2", "2    +2", "2 +2", "2+ 2"};
        for (String entry : tests) {
            System.out.println("testing entry: " + entry);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                Double num1 = new Double(matcher.group(1));
                String operand = matcher.group(2);
                Double num2 = new Double(matcher.group(3));
                System.out.printf("num1: %s, operand: %s, num2: %s\n", num1, operand, num2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However this code is rather brittle because it only works for the exact format you've specified, i.e. binary operations with integers. If you want to get more advanced you'd want to either use a Scanner or to consider using a full parser like ANTLR. ANTLR is very easy to use for this situation, in fact I think the ANTLR tutorial covers creating a calculator.

edit: This code cannot handle floating point numbers, even though it stores them in Doubles.